# create simple server with node js (custom protocol)

Tags: node.js, server, protocols, light

I have (for exercise) to create a server, to handle client connections. The subject talk about C programming, but I already did it. Id'like to do it again with node js. I don't need a http server, just a simple module which handle raw cmd. The protocol is given within the subject, and I will implement the logic of my app by my side. I am just new in node js programming, and its a light subject (about 5-6 commands). Do you know where I can start? Name/doc of a simple module, or just the minimalist code to handle client connection/command reading? (Cmds are simple strings, followed by \n). 
I've searched inside npm website, but I just find http's server or something more elaborate, and I don't need so much feature. Just connections, commands in raw format and some events to handle nicely things like connection losts, read wich failed, etc...

Comment: it's a CLI that you want create? Command Line Interface, maybe this module could help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli

Comment: No, something to connect with netcat or telnet or whatever client who juste read() and write() on his socket (in C but the client part is'nt the problem here)

Comment: if you want create a conversation 
 with a socket, maybe this module could help you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client

Comment: Quite interesting, but I just want the server side. I think it's still too much? I don't need http or real request things. My client will be connect with a hard ipv4 addr and doesn't need routes or anything...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I missed this documentation page: [Net module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/net.html)

Thank you all!